# Updating object inside redux state throws an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to update array inside object in my reducer.

```
const initialState = {
  group: {
    name: "",
    date: "",
    description: "",
    users: [],
    posts: []
  },
  morePosts: false,
  groups: []

};

export function groups(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    .......
    case REQUEST_MORE_POSTS:
      {
        return {
          ...state,
          group:{
            ...state.group,
            posts: [
              ...state.group.posts,
              ...action.payload.posts
            ]
          },
          morePosts: action.payload.morePosts
        }
      }
    case ADD_NEW_POST:
      {
        return {
          ...state,
          group:{
            ...state.group,
            posts: [
              action.payload,
              ...state.group.posts
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ........
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately in both cases I get an error:

[image: Console]

It works when I extract posts out of my group object but I need it inside.
I can't figure out what I've done wrong here. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Here is an action creator for adding new post.

```
export function addPost(url, payload) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.post(url + "php/addPostGroup.php", {payload}).then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_NEW_POST,
        payload: response.data.post
      })
    })
  }
}
```

response.data.post is a simple object.

I've added console.log() before dispatch. This is how my response looks like:
[image: console.log(response.data.post)]

Comment: On which case is it failing?

Comment: On REQUEST_MORE_POSTS as well as on ADD_NEW_POST

Comment: Can you add examples of action payload in each case to your question.

Comment: Are you sure your response is parsed to a JS object and not a string?

Comment: Yup, I'm positive

Comment: Are you sure you have babel working.. Also: can you change  `function groups(state = initialState, action) {` to `const groups = (state = initialState, action) =>`

Comment: Also can we get a console.log inside the start of your reducer groups

Answer (score 0):

Alright I solved it. Before fetching any data my state.group.posts array was for some reason treated as undefined. I had to manually declare it as empty array using

```
var posts = state.group.posts != undefined ? state.group.posts:[];
```